# Reformatting the way references to figures do appear

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

How can one make LaTeX insert Figure into `\ref` calls automatically, i.e. instead of writing:

`See data in Figure \ref{fig:JobInformationDialog}`

simply write:

`See data in \ref{fig:jobInformationDialog}`

and have LaTeX insert Figure `[fignum]` when it gets compiled?

Comment: Package `cleveref` might be of interest here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\autoref` command from the `hyperref` package. If you want to change the `Figure` part of the reference you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See data in Figure \ref{fig:JobInformationDialog}

See data in \autoref{fig:JobInformationDialog}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \fbox{JobInformationDialog}
    \caption{The Caption}
    \label{fig:JobInformationDialog}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the `Figure` part of the reference you can redefine `\figureautorefname`

```
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Illustration}
```